# Show heart rate from IOS app on WatchKit app continuously

Tags: ios, watchkit, rate

I am wondering what would be best practice to display the heart rate which I get from the BLE heart rate monitor to my IOS app on WatchKit app. A direkt transfer is not possible. I am thinking of a timer which fires every second on the IOS app and transfers the actual heart rate to the SharedDefaults. On the WatchKit app I am also implementing a timer which reads every second from the SharedDefaults. Could that be a good solution?

// Create and share access to an NSUserDefaults object.
NSUserDefaults *mySharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"com.example.domain.MyShareExtension"];

// Use the shared user defaults object to update the user's account.
[mySharedDefaults setObject:bpm forKey:@"heartrate"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also pass data from your iPhone app to your WatchKit extension using https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole and then you don't need to rely on an always running timer.

Comment: Seems to be exact what I need. But I can't get it to work. I created my own App Group and replaced the original group with my identifier. The example app is build without any error. But no data is passed. I was not able to pod install --> no 'Podfile' found. I think at problem is with the "Embedded Binaries" under "General". The two binaries are red -> MMWormhole WatchKit Extension.appex and Today Extension.appex any idea? Thanks Ron

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure on that error.  You may want to do a new SO question.